# Getting data from SQL Server 2008 with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm having some difficulties getting data from a simple stored procedure in SQL Server working.  I have a Powershell script that needs to get variables filled from 3 columns (the procedure just returns 1 row)

Here's what I have that isn't working.  Somehow I'm not referencing the column value correctly.  I've tried various methods, but usually get the error "Cannot index into a null array".  I don't want to iterate through the resultset, I just want to directly set some values from the one row returned into variables

```
$conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = `
  "Server=ServerName;Database=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True"
$sqlQuery = new-object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$sqlQuery.Add("JobSettingsGet")
$Resultset = $conn.ExecuteWithResults($sqlQuery)

# $UserName = $table.Rows(0).Columns(0) 
  # error - Method invocation failed because [System.Data.DataTable] doesn't 
  # contain a method named 'Rows'.
# $UserName = $table.Rows[0].Columns[0] 
  # error - cannot index null array
# $UserName = $table.Row(0).Column(0) 
  # error - Cannot index into a null array,  also Method invocation failed 
  # because [System.Data.DataTable] doesn't contain a method named 'Row'.
# $UserName = $table.Rows[0].Columns[1].Value 
  # error - cannot index null array
```

I'd like to use the column name if possible, too.

Any pointers?

thanks,
Sylvia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` instead of `SqlServer.Management` class

```
$conn = New-Object Data.Sqlclient.Sqlconnection`
    ("Data Source=DATABASE;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
$adapter = New-Object Data.Sqlclient.Sqldataadapter("exec sp_who2", $conn)
$set = new-object data.dataset
$adapter.fill($set)
$table = new-object data.datatable
$table = $set.tables[0]
```

In order to print the whole table, just use `format-table`

```
$table | ft -AutoSize
```

To get a column by name, use the foreach iterator and access note properties by name

```
$table | % {$_.login}
```

Ed: Here is the same query by using SqlServer.Management.

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName`
   ("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")
$conn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = `
   "Server=ServerName;Database=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True"
$sqlQuery = new-object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection 
$sqlQuery.Add("exec sp_who2") 
$resultset = $conn.ExecuteWithResults($sqlQuery)
```

Access the results by picking the zeroeth resultset, zeroeth table, zeroeth row and item by name

```
$resultset[0].tables.Item(0).Rows[0].Item("Login")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I can connect to the db, and using the foreach iterator works.  However, what I'd like to do is (since I know there's only 1 row with 3 columns) get the actual data into variables without iterating.  Something like below (which gives the error "Cannot index into a null array") :

$UserName = $table.rows[0].columns[0]

Comment: $table.rows[0] ought to be System.Data.DataRow which doesn't have Columns member. Try using item() method: $table.Rows[0].item("Login").

Comment: Thanks, it works now.  Any comment on when it would be best to use sqldataadapter instead of the other data access methods (ExecuteWithResults, etc)